# Android not preloading image

Tags: android, image, android-webview

I am loading an image into my webview and then showing it on a click. Since I've loaded the webview before the click, I expect the image to be shown instantly. But it takes a second to load. How can I get the image to show instantly. Here is my code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        LinearLayout layout = new LinearLayout(this);
        layout.setOrientation(LinearLayout.VERTICAL);
        final WebView webView = new WebView(this);

        String url = "http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/d/d8/Deerfire_high_res_edit.jpg";
        String html = "<!doctype html><html lang='en'><head></head><body>Hello World<img src='" + url + "'></body></html>";
        webView.loadDataWithBaseURL("", html, "text/html", "UTF-8", "");
        Button button = new Button(this);
        button.setText("Click me!");
        button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {      
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {           
                setContentView(webView);                
            }
        });     
        layout.addView(button);
        setContentView(layout);
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This might be a bit hacky, but I would think you could set the webview visiblility to gone or invisible... `webView.setVisibility(View.GONE);` or `webView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);`, then do the image loading into the view, then in the `onClick` method make it visible  `webView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);` It might be loaded there already and simply appear.

Note:  untested and possible hacky solution.

After re-reading this, you would have to have a layout as a parent to the webView.  You would set the parent in `setContentView(parent)` then get the webView, add it to the parent, assign the image and then do the visibility stuff.